# Encoding and Decoding Bytes in Python

Tags: python

I'm dealing with a communication channel that:

- Converts `\n` characters into `\r\n`
- Removes `0xfd`, `0xfe`, and `0xff` characters entirely

Not ideal for transferring binary data.
I can effectively use base64 to transfer binary data through it, but this makes the data being transferred 33% larger, which, when dealing with large amounts of binary data like I am, kinda sucks.

A simple, not entirely efficient way to use Python to create my own encoding is this:

```py
escape_char = b'='

# These are the bytes we don't want in our stream
bytes_to_escape = b'\n\xfd\xfe\xff'

# This is a mapping of the bytes being replaced, with the bytes we're
# replacing them with
replacements = {
    escape_char: escape_char,
    **{
        byte: i.to_bytes(1, "big")
        for i, byte in enumerate([bytes([b]) for b in bytes_to_escape])
    }
}

# Reverse mapping, for decoding
reverse_replacements = {v: k for k, v in replacements.items()}

# Encoder
def encode(data: bytes) -> bytes:
    result = b''

    for byte in [bytes([i]) for i in data]:
        replacement = replacements.get(byte)
        if replacement:
            result += escape_char + replacement
        else:
            result += byte

    return result

# Decoder
def decode(data: bytes) -> bytes:
    result = b''
    i = 0

    while i < len(data):
        current_byte = bytes([data[i]])
        next_byte = bytes([data[i+1]]) if i+1 < len(data) else None

        if current_byte == escape_char:
            if not next_byte:
                result += current_byte
            else:
                replacement = reverse_replacements[next_byte]
                result += replacement
                i += 1
        else:
            result += current_byte

        i += 1

    return result
```

This will essentially:

- Escape the `=` character with `==`, because it's used as our escape character
- Convert `\n` to `0x00`
- Convert `0xfd` to `0x01`
- Convert `0xfe` to `0x02`
- Convert `0xff` to `0x03`

Is there a way to make this more efficient, short of writing it in a low-level language as a python module? Maybe something that uses regex might work faster?

Comment: "This works, until ..." Does your code work as expected or not?

Comment: @RichardNeumann it does what it's told to do, but doesn't handle some types of input data

Comment: I would suggest that you think of and implement a working encoding first and come back with that working encoding later, which we then can review.

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We only review code that is working as expected, there are other sites that will help you debug your code. Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Now it works for all cases

Comment: Thanks for editing - it looks reviewable now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### bytes

You are working with `bytes` which is very cumbersome.

- You have to prefix all literals
- single bytes have type int and need to be converted to to bytes again
  At least I cannot do this without debugging some errors.

It is much more convenient to work with strings. So I suggest to decode the bytes to a string with an 8-bit codec like 'latin-1'.
No more `bytes([x])` or `x.to_bytes()`. You can use plain comprehension, plain `''.join()`, etc.
If required you encode the string to bytes again with the very same codec.

### dict.get()

For conditional translations there is a nice trick - `dict.get()` - which allows to pass a default value for non-existing keys.

```
translated = replacements.get(char, char)
```

This returns `replacements[char]` if `char` is in `replacements.keys()`. Otherwise it returns the default `char`.
To use this functionality you include the escape character in the translation table (however you fill it).

```
replacements = {escape_char: escape_char + escape_char,
       '\n':   escape_char + '\x00',
       '\xfd': escape_char + '\x01',
       '\xfe': escape_char + '\x02',
       '\xff': escape_char + '\x03',
       }
```

The encoding function now reads

```
def encode(data: bytes) -> bytes:
    str_data = data.decode(encoding='latin-1')
    str_enc = ''.join(replacements.get(x, x) for x in str_data)
    return str_enc.encode(encoding='latin-1')
```

### loop like a pro

In your decoding function you loop over `len(data)` which is an anti-pattern. You should always loop over the elements. To make it worse you use a while loop and increment the loop counter manually. You also access elements with index `i+1` which again is error prone.
Loop over elements only and keep a little state like a `previous_byte`. You cannot be out of bounds.

```
def decode(data: bytes) -> bytes:
    d_data = data.decode(encoding='latin-1')
    l = []
    esc = ''
    for x in d_data:
        if not esc and x == escape_char:
            esc = x
            continue
        l.append(reverse_replacements.get(esc + x, esc + x))
        esc = ''
    assert esc == ''
    return ''.join(l).encode(encoding='latin-1)')
```

### testing

For your nicely testable functions you should provide some tests. There are unit test frameworks available.
You can also do the most primitive assertions, of course in a main guard.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert encode(b"asdf") == b"asdf"
    assert decode(b"asdf") == b"asdf"

    assert encode(b"as\ndf") == b"as=\x00df"
    assert decode(b"as=\x00df") == b"as\ndf"
    assert encode(b"\ndf") == b"=\x00df"
    assert decode(b"=\x00df") == b"\ndf"
    assert encode(b"as\n") == b"as=\x00"
    assert decode(b"as=\x00") == b"as\n"

    assert encode(b"as\xfddf") == b"as=\x01df"
    assert decode(b"as=\x01df") == b"as\xfddf"

    assert encode(b"as\xfedf") == b"as=\x02df"
    assert decode(b"as=\x02df") == b"as\xfedf"

    assert encode(b"as\xffdf") == b"as=\x03df"
    assert decode(b"as=\x03df") == b"as\xffdf"
```